# Align Parent Bottom With Below RelativeLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Good day.I have an set of buttons which should be aligned to the bottom always,but they all also should be below an text,and it goes like this,if text is large,it is going just to push the buttons inside the scrollview,otherwise the buttons should be aligned to the parent bottom.Issue is that i add both of the tags to the linear layout wrapper of the buttons,but as soon as i set visibility of text to gone,the view just pops up and not aligning to parent bottom,here is the actual code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_product_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_placeholder" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/basket_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/basket_success_icon"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
                android:src="@drawable/success_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_product_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/basket_success_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_success_icon"
                android:text="@string/product_added_to_basket_text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_image"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:background="#D1D3D4">

        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:text="@string/loading_text"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_weight_and_servings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/single_product_divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/weight_and_servings_text"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/single_product_weight_and_servings"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/single_product_weight_and_servings"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_weight_and_servings"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="$12.09"
            android:textColor="#009444"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/single_product_rating"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/single_product_price"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/single_product_price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_price"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:numStars="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_rating_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/single_product_rating"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/single_product_rating"
            android:text="10.0/10"
            android:textColor="#231F20"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_review_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/single_product_rating_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/single_product_rating_text"
            android:text="8 reviews"
            android:textColor="#EC2027"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_stock_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/single_product_review_count"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="In stock"
            android:textColor="#939598" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/single_product_center_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_rating"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></View>


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/single_product_weight_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_rating"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/single_product_center_divider"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/single_product_type_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_rating"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/single_product_center_divider"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"></Spinner>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_product_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_type_spinner"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="This is simply the best tripod for the money you\'ll ever buy,it\'s rock solid and the head alone is worth more then the asking price"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/single_product_buttons_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_description"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/single_product_add_to_cart_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#F26522"
                android:text="@string/add_to_cart_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/single_product_info_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_add_to_cart_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#E7E8E9"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_info_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#231F20" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/single_product_nutritional_info_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_info_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#E7E8E9"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_nutritional_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#231F20" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/single_product_reviews_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_nutritional_info_button"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#E7E8E9"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_reviews_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#231F20" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can anyone please give any suggestion?

Edit : The full code of the view,actual buttons are inside RelativeLayout at the bottom of xml files there are 4 of buttons.The wrapper is single_product_buttons_wrapper

Comment: it is 5th time im asking on stackoverflow and no answer at all,and question is not high mathematics...what happened to stackoverflow?

Comment: u only have put the question 4 mins ago. BTW, you mention scrollView. where is it. And I see you xml has a RelativeLayout. But i didnt see on the top. so is that the outer layer of the xml?

Comment: yes there is,let me fully update it

Comment: so what you want is the buttons stay at bottom? My answer as below. Assume there is a Relativelayout outside.

Comment: yes correct,that is what i want and meanwhile to have that buttons also be always below the text

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="bottom"` to `LinearLayout` containing buttons. It will work have tested it.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/single_product_description"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: wonderfull!!! Working like a charm!The issue was the gravity,as soon as i added gravity instead of align parent bottom all working like tici taca ! :) thank you!!!!!!!!!!You saved my day!Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_product_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="This is simply the best tripod for the money you\'ll ever buy,it\'s rock solid and the head alone is worth more then the asking price"
        android:textColor="#231F20" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/single_product_add_to_cart_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/single_product_info_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#F26522"
            android:text="123"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/single_product_info_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/single_product_nutritional_info_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#E7E8E9"

            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="234"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/single_product_nutritional_info_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/single_product_reviews_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#E7E8E9"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="5555"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/single_product_reviews_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#E7E8E9"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="99999"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#231F20" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunatally this is not helping

Comment: but still nice approach